# Loading Data From Table1 then Save to Table2

Tags: vb.net, datagrid

I need to load data from Table 1. After loading it to a datagrid view, I have to save it to another table (Table2).

```
'' Load data
            Dim cmdSQL As String = "SELECT * FROM Table1"
            Dim ds_Tbl As New DataSet
            Dim cmdBuilder As New SqlClient.SqlCommandBuilder
            Dim da As New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(cmdSQL, connection)
            cmdBuilder = New SqlCommandBuilder(da)
            da.Fill(ds_Tbl, "Table2")
            dgvTables.DataSource = ds_Tbl.Tables(0) '
```

`'' Save data
                Me.Validate()
                da.Update(ds_Tbl.Tables("Table2"))
                ds_Tbl.AcceptChanges()`

I prefer to use command builder because this code is placed inside a loop for me to able to load various tables to one datagrid one at a time then save it to other designated table. Loading went okay but saving was unsuccessful. Please help.

Comment: what is your update command in da?

Comment: @F0r3v3r-A-N00b , how am i going to insert update command in that line of code?

Comment: You have to set the UpdateCommand property of the data adapter to the sql command that you want to execute when you call da.Update